# Automation test project with Selenium

Tags: java, maven, selenium, junit

I need to automate a lot of manual tests on the browser gui (200+).
I would like to use Selenium Webdriver, but I have doubts about the structure of the Java project.
Some examples that I have seen on the net, include the insertion of Selenium commands within the JUnit tests (@Test).
On the one hand this thing would help me to distinguish the tests, but on the one hand it doesn't make much sense, since the JUnit test is a unitary test (Each test involves a phase of reading data input from the database). 
Currently I have created all classes under src/test/java, but in src/main/java what should be put ? 
Also in the final phase and distribution what release ? A folder with the sources where I start the tests with the "mvn test" command ?
Selenium seems widespread, but on the net I can't find "serious" projects

Comment: For release you can build an executable jar file that runs and produces your results/reports.  (you can run it as a scheduled task if you like, too.)  I'm not sure I understand all your questions, though.  What IDE are you using?

Comment: The base question is whether the Selenium tests are being run against an application that's part of the same packaging (i.e., the application is in `src/main` and the tests are in `src/test`) or whether the test suite is a whole-system integration suite that's run externally, such as by a scheduled runner, and therefore is "it's own" program.

Comment: how can I generate a jar and make it run all the tests? I can't create a main class in src / main that calls the tests in src / test. The main class cannot see the test classes.
No, I want to create a project that only does this. That is, you launch a series of tests automatically. For this reason I asked, in this case in src / main I will not put anything?

Comment: Try Katalon studio. You don't need much to code and creating tests/test suites is pretty much easier. Selenium is built-in you can use all it's magic.